# Retrieving path to handle files making troubles during testing

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, ant, powermock

I am working on my Ant builder for my program, specifically onto handling path to files.

I reached a solution very simple adding in my Constant interface just two fields:

```
/** The actual jar file where the class is run */
public static final File JAR_FILE = new File(MagicHogwarts.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());

/** The path to the main folder where the file .jar is run */
public static final String BASE_DIRECTORY = JAR_FILE.getAbsolutePath().replace(JAR_FILE.getName(), "");
```

In each method that handle a file I simply ask for the path relative the main folder where the jar is and then add the BASE_DIRECTORY first, this is working fine at least in macOSX both in eclipse that running the jar.

Happy with this quick solution I run my tests. That failed.
The problem seems to be in the Constants interface, it's impossible to create `JAR_FILE`, because `getLocation` returns null, and then `getPath` fails.

But I can't understand why.

So I tried to mock the interface, with obvious problems due to the fact that the var is declared static final, so I tried with PowerMock:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({GameWindow.class,Constants.class})
public class MapReaderTest {

@Test
public void testReadingExampleMap() throws Exception {
    mockStatic(GameWindow.class);
            mockStatic(Constants.class);
    TextureLoader tl = createMock(TextureLoader.class);
    Texture tx = createMock(Texture.class);
    expect(GameWindow.getTextureLoader()).andReturn(tl);
            expect(Constants.BASE_DIRECTORY).andReturn("/Users/Gianmarco/Documents/java/MagicHogwarts/").anyTimes();
    expect(tl.getTexture("/Users/Gianmarco/Documents/java/MagicHogwarts/bin/mh/test/sewer_tileset.png")).andReturn(tx);
    expect(tx.getImageHeight()).andReturn(32).anyTimes();
    expect(tx.getImageWidth()).andReturn(32).anyTimes();
    replay(GameWindow.class);
            replay(Constants.class);
    replay(tl);
    replay(tx);

    // Act
    Map map = new TMXMapReader().readMap("/bin/mh/test/sewers.tmx");//mapFile.getAbsolutePath());

    // Assert
    assertEquals(Map.ORIENTATION_ORTHOGONAL, map.getOrientation());
    assertEquals(50, map.getHeight());
    assertEquals(50, map.getHeight());
    assertEquals(24, map.getTileWidth());
    assertEquals(24, map.getTileHeight());
    assertEquals(2, map.getLayerCount());
}
}
```

But I got an ExceptionInInitializerError, line 60 of Constants, that is the line where JAR_FILE is declared, the error was caused by a NullPointerException.

The next step I thought was to transform the interface to a class, maybe powermock was not able to handle interfaces in that way.

Run, and got a NoClassDefFoundError.
Still no results, I cannot figure out what to do. So I tried reflection.

I used this static method:

```
static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
    field.setAccessible(true);

    // remove final modifier from field
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    field.set(null, newValue);
}
```

calling it with:

```
setFinalStatic(Constants.class.getField("JAR_FILE"), null);
setFinalStatic(Constants.class.getField("BASE_DIRECTORY"), "my/path/hardcoded");
```

But neither this worked, I got an ExceptionInInitializerError with a stack that contains `sun.mic.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)`, sun.reflect and others.

I spent hours with this problem and I came to the conclusion that the problem is with JAR_FILE, and the method that are used to initialize it, because even removing `final` modifier from the constants I was not able to change the value calling `Constants.JAR_FILE = null`

The thing that I did as solution of the problem is this:

```
/** The actual jar file where the class is run */
    public static final File    JAR_FILE            = (MagicHogwarts.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() == null ? null : new File(MagicHogwarts.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()));

    /** The path to the main folder where the file .jar is run */
    public static final String  BASE_DIRECTORY      = (JAR_FILE != null ? JAR_FILE.getAbsolutePath().replace(JAR_FILE.getName(), "") : "/Users/Gianmarco/Documents/java/MagicHogwarts/");
```

that is a rude and very unpleasant and horrid way of using an if statement.

My question is, **is there any different method to get the base-dir of the jar and/or the file that is called with `#java Myclass` from terminal line that can be used both in normal processing (also jar) and testing**?

The solution I reached is working but I don't think is a good thing to hardcode some testing code into a class, in fact using the if is like telling Constants class "if I am testing, give me this mock string, else give me the real path". That if is not useful in normal program behavior, I whould like to leave my test code separated from my classes (as it should be).

Comment: There are various hacks you can do to get the location of a JAR file, and you've tried some. It sounds like when tests are run, you are running against raw ``.class`` files and there **is** no JAR file.

Look for a way to leverage ``Class.getResource()`` or ``Class.getResourceAsStream()`` and have what you need visible on your test classpath, instead of looking for files on disk at all.

Also, remember that static constant Strings are inlined, and are dangerous to use for things which are subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

When testing one shouldn't be relying on absolute paths as it makes test brittle and non-portable.

Instead of absolute paths, one should look for resources. It's better to use Class.getResource or Class.getResourceAsStream to read.

For the former you can retrieve a URL. If necessary this can be turn back into an absolute path by using the url.toExternalForm but once you have the resource you need that should really be sufficient.